# Logo png image not loading through webpack

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack

I want the logo png file to display

The image is supposed to load once the web pack is started right now I can only get the HTML, css, and some fonts while the logo does not display.

Error messages

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/forkify/dist/css/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
test.js:5 Imported module
index.js:14 Uncaught ReferenceError: element is not defined
    at eval (index.js:14)
    at Module../src/js/index.js (bundle.js:398)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:432)
    at bundle.js:526
    at bundle.js:529
logo.png:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I have tried file and uri loader on the webpack but still having same issue.

index.js

```
import num from './test';
import '../../dist/css/style.css';
import Logo from '../../dist/img/logo.png';

// Add the image to our existing div.
const myIcon = new Image();
myIcon.src = Logo;

element.appendChild(myIcon);

console.log(`I imported ${num} from another module test!`);
```

Webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports={
    entry:'./src/js/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename:'js/bundle.js'
    
    },
    // mode: 'development' // Dont compress or minify codes and enable quick loading
    devServer: {
        contentBase:'./dist'
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: './src/index.html'
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.css$/i,
            use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
          },
          {
            test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/i,
            // More information here https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/
            type: "asset/resource",
          },
        ],
    },

};
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "forkify",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Food app project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "start:dev": "webpack serve --mode development --open"
  },
  "author": "BrewedLeo",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.20.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

[image: file layout]

Comment: where is `element` in  `element.appendChild(myIcon);` coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you missed in your webpack.config.json under rules outputPath like after test:  /.(png|.... than define loader: 'file-loader', and insert path:
options: {
outputPath: 'images',
}
For me, it is easier with copy-webpack-plugin than you can copy files in your dist..

```js
plugins: [
        new CopyPlugin({
            patterns: [
                { from: "src/img", to: "img/" },
            ],
        }),
    ]
```

...and element is missing